# Holding Super Key doesn't show Unity shortcuts

Tags: unity, launcher, shortcut-keys

As the title states, when I hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key Unity shortcuts list doesn't appear.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 (fresh install). I can see the dock that shows up with numbers on icons to launch applications. Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your screen's resolution? The keyboard shortcut list is not displayed on small monitors.

Comment: I haven't tested, but it seems legit

Comment: my resolution is 1024x600, the screen is 10"

Comment: That's too small for the shortcut list

Comment: Do you know what the cut-off is?  (Works on my 13" screen, e.g..)

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure it is configured to show the shortcuts running this at terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/shortcut_overlay TRUE
```

In Ubuntu 12.10, this would be:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/shortcut_overlay TRUE
```